# Finite sum of hypergeometric $_{2}F_{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

I need to find an expression for this finite sum

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\,_{2}F_{3}\left(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2}+n-k,\frac{1}{2}+k,n;z\right),
$$

where $_{2}F_{3}$ is a hypergeometric function. Can you shed light on this or suggest some useful references?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$
E_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\,_{2}F_{3}\left(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2}+n-k,\frac{1}{2}+k,n;z\right) .
$$
According to Maple,
$$
E_0 = \cosh(2\sqrt{z})\\
E_1 = \frac{\sinh(2\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}
$$
But then it only says
$$
E_2=
2\,{\mbox{$_2$F$_3$}\left(1,\frac{3}{2};\,\frac{1}{2},2,\frac{5}{2};\,z\right)}+2\,
{\mbox{$_1$F$_2$}\left(1;\,\frac{3}{2},2;\,z\right)}
\\
E_3 =
2\,{\mbox{$_2$F$_3$}\left(\frac{3}{2},2;\,\frac{1}{2},3,\frac{7}{2};\,z\right)}+6\,
{\mbox{$_1$F$_2$}\left(2;\,\frac{5}{2},3;\,z\right)}
$$

Comment: Thanks! What about a reference I can consult?